# Precision-Recall curves with multiclass classifier

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, precision-recall

I would like to plot the PR curves for a multiclass classifier (e.g. 3 classes). In the documentation it states that multiclass is not supported, and instead a series of one vs all classifiers are fitted, then their PR curves plotted - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html

However this is not helpful for me, as I'm trying to evaluate my own multi-class classifier (which is also not supported by scikit's wrappers). Can I just plot the PR curves using the predictions from my classifier, i.e. given multiclass `Y_test` and `y_score`, use this snippet:

```
for i in range(n_classes):
    precision[i], recall[i], _ = precision_recall_curve(Y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    average_precision[i] = average_precision_score(Y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
```

I can use `average_precision_score` with 'average=None' and compute the per-PR curve AUC for each class with the same outputs as above, so I would expect this to work, but I am not sure how correct it will be.

Comment: Stackoverflow could be a better venue to ask this and there is a relevant post there too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090541/how-to-plot-precision-and-recall-of-multiclass-classifier